# How Integrate SAP Fiori App and IBM Mobile First

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, sap-fiori

I am trying to Integrate existing **SAP FIORI** App in **IBM Mobile First**. I want to render the SAP FIORI App launch pad on mobile screen and would like to customize the app also.

I can able to integrate SAP backend system by using **SAP Netweaver Gateway Adapters** in MF. Here we are consuming OData Services and can able to get the data.

Is there any possibility to launch the existing sap fiori app in MF ?

Can any one help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear. There is no integration limitation with MFP...

If you are developing a native application then this question is unrelated; MFP does not control your UI, it only provides (among other things) a security framework to use.

If you are developing a Hybrid application, this FIORI thing is a framework, then you need only to add it.

You do not explain what you have tried and if you are failing, where you are failing at.

Comment: Actually I am searching for the possibility for integration and I have no clue that whether the SAP Fiori App is providing as a framework/Odata service or not. Here I am developing Hybrid Application

Comment: Then this is really not a question for MFP; it's a question for SAP.

Comment: Can we consume a framework page in MF, because SAP is providing Fiori framework page. Once look into this http://scn.sap.com/community/enterprise-portal/blog/2014/11/10/fiori-framework-page-the-new-recommended-framework-page-for-mobile-consumption

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "consuming a framework page".

Comment: In the blog which I sent you, they mentioned " Fiori framework page is the recommended framework page for consuming the SAP Portal on mobile devices" like this. So can we do this in MF ?

Comment: As I see it, this "framework page" (awful name) is running on a server and the mobile device connects to this server; that server's contents is then displayed in a mobile-friendly UI. For that matter, it sounds like you can simply open a webview in your app and display that site's content.

Comment: Can you send me any reference link regarding this.

Comment: This: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/integrating-server-generated-pages-hybrid-applications/ or this: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/using-a-mobilefirst-application-as-a-container-for-server-generated-pages/ or this: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/container-advanced-pages/

Comment: Thank you for reference links , Can we customize the mobile-friendly UI ??

Comment: Ask SAP. They provide the UI here.